# Curve effect on a rectangle Silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

How can i create a curve shape in the middle of the rectangle in silverlight

Thanks,
J

Comment: Please provide a picture of what you need. I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

As the rectangle is not a container, you have to "paint" your curve over the rectangle. Unless you use a Path to draw both.

Comment: is it possible to create the curve on a border? or have to do the same thing

Comment: What do you mean by a curve on the border?

Comment: Curve as in middle of the border to make it look like almost a semi cylinder

Comment: Basically a Path object can be used to draw "any" shape. If you have Blend this would be easy, if not, have to manually calculate every point coordinate for the path.